# Where can I show the hybrid app to my client?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

I wonder if it exists a way to show to my client how the app looks like.. I mean a simulator in cloud or something like that, i'm doing the app with ionic.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So Ionic (2+) app can potentially "be" available:

**Locally:**

- via ionic serve (web app)
- via device run type commands (hybrid with access to plugins) on target platforms (iOS/Android)

**Remotely:**

- via Ionic Pro / Ionic View - (~web-app with limited plugins access) -
  gets depreciated [very soon](https://blog.ionicframework.com/ionic-view-sunsetting-on-9-1-18/)
- via platforms relevant store's test solution: [testflight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) (iOS)
  or Google Play's beta testing (via Google dev console)
- via remote access to devices (like [Firebase's test lab](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/?authuser=0) or [AWS
  device farm](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm))

So in your case it really depends on your app:

if you are ***using native plugins*** the most accessible would probably be an option via Android devices as Google is much less restrictive towards sideloading of apps to their devices. This still may require additional steps from you clients (like following installation instructions). If you client is not tech savvy it is probably best to look into Google Play's beta testing program that they offer (via their console)

if you are not using any native plugins - then it is fairly easy to [deploy your app as progressive web app](https://www.joshmorony.com/hosting-an-ionic-pwa-with-firebase-hosting/) (upload it to a hosting like firebase hosting) and provide access to it.